A mathematical object that can be an element of a matrix.
I read the definition of matrix on wikipedia. However, if you read this content, you can see the following phrase.

In mathematics, a matrix (pl.: matrices) is a rectangular array or table of numbers, symbols, or expressions, with elements or entries arranged in rows and columns, which is used to represent a mathematical object or property of such an object.

Reading this passage reminded me of the mathematical definitions of a matrix ring or a polynomial matrix. And then I naturally became curious about the objects of the elements of the matrix. Does it matter what mathematical objects can be in the elements of the matrix? If there are any restrictions, what are the restrictions?

If you want to add and multiply matrices, their entries should be elements of a ring

It is quite common to consider matrices over fields.  Fields have sets with elements which are equipped with addition, multiplication and their inverses subtraction and division. There must exist a 0 and 1 element so that they are identities for addition and multiplication respectively. Additionally 0 needs to multiply everything to itself. Some of the most famous fields are Z, Q, R, C. (integers, fractions of integers, real and complex numbers.)

Formally, a matrix is a function (!) $$A: \{1,...,m\}\times \{1,...,n\}\to K, (i,j)\mapsto a_{ij},$$ where $K$ is some set. The rectangular array is notatio rather than notio. I don't think there are any restrictions on what $K$ can be – on a formal level! By the way, a function is a special relation, which itself is  a subset of a certain cartesian product. So, a matrix is, at its core, a set.
However, the nature and utility of such matrices depend significantly on the properties of the underlying set.

As an example of the last sentence: if you want matrices which can be added and multiplied, then the matrix elements themselves should be able to be added and multiplied. Hence the typical focus on matrix rings.

It depends how you are using the matrices.
In the usual way, where matrices represent linear transformations between vector spaces, the entries live in a field. This is naturally relaxed to just requiring a ground ring, so addition and multiplication make sense and are compatible via the distributive property. For example, one can work with matrices over the integers.
However, there are specialized contexts where one could conceivably work with an even weaker class of objects for the entries, say a semiring where multiplication makes sense, but not necessarily subtraction.
Or the most general context is where the objects live in an abelian category, which can be quite abstract. There are categories built out (co-)bordisms where it's natural to consider matrices whose entries look like these surfaces and "multiplication" consists of gluing them together and addition is formal.


But matrices don't only work to represent linear transformations. Instead, they could describe a bilinear form or a pairing. For example, an inner product like the familiar dot product of vectors.
Or the adjacency matrix or incidence matrix from graph theory. Or even to represent an abstract relation, where the operations are on a boolean algebra: "multiplication" is meet (a.k.a. and, a.k.a. $\land$) and "addition" is join (a.k.a. or, a.k.a. $\lor$).

Basically, any time one wishes to doubly-index some collection of objects, the matrix is the tool. With a single index, we get the components of vectors. With zero indices, we get scalars themselves. And in the other direction, we get tensors of higher rank.

In my experience, for a 2d list to properly be called a matrix it needs to be a ring with addition defined componentwise and multiplication defined by the usual matrix multiplication rule. This entails that we need some concept of multiplying and adding elements of the matrix, which in practice will almost always mean a ring.
